# How to get rid of a global.target within the terminal on MacOS?

Tags: python, terminal, global

I have run into this problem where anything I install with pip installs to my main location of python and not to my virtual environments.

The following line is what I get when I run: python3 -pip config list

Coles-MacBook-Air:/ colekellow$ python3 -m pip config list
global.target='/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages'

I do not know how to get rid of the global.target and have looked around to no avail. I have found a post on github where someone had the global.target, but there was no suggestion on how to remove it. Any and all help will be appreciated thanks.

Comment: If you're inside your virtual environment, just try running "python" rather than "python3".  You're probably getting the global python rather than the "inside-your-environment" Python

Comment: Thank you. I crossposted on GitHub and someone responded with another way to remove the global.target function. Your response also seemed to work as well.

Answer (score 0):

This post was cross-posted to GitHub. On GitHub, chrysle responded with an answer that worked to remove the global.target using:

`pip config unset global.target`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).